# Вопрос про "ArgumentCountError"

Tags: php

Имеем класс Address с конструктором

```
 public function __construct(string $country,string $city, string $street, string $house, string $building = '') {}
```

Я хочу валидировать все части адреса (страну, город, улицу, дом, строение). Это всё удается

```
 private function isCountryValid($param) {
    if (empty($param) || !preg_match("/^[а-яё0-9- ]+$/iu", $param)) {
        throw new AddressWithoutCountryException($param);
    }
}
```

и тест удается нормально написать

```
 public function testAddressCreatedWithoutCountry() {
    $this->expectException(AddressWithoutCountryException::class);
    CreateCompanyBuilder::instance()->withAddress(new Address('', 'Москва', 'Солнечная', '15',''))->build();
}
```

Но что делать, если я хочу сделать тест без параметров вообще

```
 public function testCreateCompanyWithoutAddress() {
    $this->expectException(CompanycWithoutAddressException::class);
    CreateCompanyBuilder::instance()->withAddress(new Address())->build();
}
```

В этом случае логично выдается

```
Failed asserting that exception of type "ArgumentCountError" matches expected exception ... at least 4 expected
```

Вопрос номер один - как переопределить ArgumentCountError, (и где) чтобы выдавать исключение вроде

```
class CompanyWithoutAddressException extends ArgumentCountError {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('У организации должен быть заполнен адрес');
}
```

Сейчас всё равно бросается исключение `ArgumentCountError` даже если сделать так

```
public function __construct(string $country,string $city, string $street, string $house, string $building = '0') {
    if (!$country && !$city && !$street && !$house) {
        throw new CompanyWithoutAddressException();
    }
```

И второй вопрос - как лучше сделать передачу параметров в конструктор
`string $country,string $city, string $street, string $house, string $building = ''` с необязательным параметром $building (строение). Оно может быть, а может не быть. Можно убрать его из конструктора и передавать сеттером, но хотелось бы прям целиком dto засовывать в конструктор.

Comment: у вас аргументы `$country, $city, $street, $house` обязательные. Вы или присвойте им значение по умолчанию, как у `$building`. Или передавайте пустую строку, когда создаёте класс

Comment: Видимо, я плохо сформулировал вопрос, сорри. Я и хочу, чтобы они были обязательными. И хочу, чтобы кидалось исключение когда они пустые. И пустое значение конструктор пропускает. Но не пропускает, когда вообще нет никаких значений `new Address()`. Там выбрасывается `ArgumentCountException`. Но как предопределить его, чтобы кидалось моё исключение, когда не передаются обязательные параметры конструктора

Comment: Ну так если у вас проверка идёт ниже, то какая разница что у вас аргументы конструктора необязательные?!